# JavaScript dummy/proxy input for another DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I'm using an iframe to get the content of a registration form on a web page, and, as I have to show this registration form inside an HTML app for Android, I'd like to analyse the html inside the iframe to search for input textfields and to use my custom text field as "dummy" or "proxy" for the considered element:

Let me explain better:

As the web page wouldn't give the user the same easy approach as an app, instead of clicking on a textfield and having the problem that the virtual keyboard overlaps the other fields making it difficult to go further.

I want to create a div that covers the iframe and has a text field inside with the same functionality as the one clicked: by this way after entering the text into the dummy field and clicking an ok button aside, the clicked field would be updated and all the other things hidden (virtual keyboard, etc.).

It would be simple if the goal was just to copy a text from a field to another, but the real problem is that the clicked field could have some events like onkeypress or onchange (e.g. to autocomplete) and so on, and I should get the same behaviour on the dummy field.

In an imaginary world I'd do:

```
document.getElementById("dummy") = document.getElementById("original")
```

And then destroying and recreating the dummy whenever required.

Do you know if is there something possible to do?

Comment: This is exactly what phishers and other nefarious hackers do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a div from inside of an iframe after the iframe has loaded.  The reason for this is to prevent hackers from making programs that can grab your credit card numbers from web-based forms through iframes and then use the apps to record them.

**UPDATE**

You would have to  retrieve the entire form in the background, then render it again using webkit,  then when the person clicks submit, you would have to submit the exact same form data to the host from your device.

Its possible, but I don't see a good reason why you would ever need to use that.